# Zabbix integration with AWS Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, zabbix

I am trying to integrate Zabbix with AWS Elasticache. Zabbix is installed on a VM running on Oracle Virtual Box on my Laptop.

I have followed the steps mentioned in  https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch for this integration.

I have imported the template https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch/blob/master/templates/Template_AWS_ElastiCache_redis.xml as mentioned on the link.
[image]

I have created a host as shown in the below screenshot
[image]

I have executed the script https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch/blob/master/cron.d/cron.ElastiCache.sh as shown in the below screenshot
[image]

However, I am not able to get any metrics getting populated as shown in below screenshot
[image]

Please help me know where I have gone wrong and what is it that I am missing?

Comment: Show details and see why that item is unsupported. Is the agent able to talk with the server? Did you check it's not a network/firewall issue?

Comment: There is no network/firewall issue. All the firewalls are disabled. The host is configured to listen to the master on 10051. Please help me know how I can check the reason for the item being unsupported. Please help me know if any screenshot is needed.

Comment: To see why it's unsupported, go to Item list in the Host Inventory, look for the item and click on the red marker in the far right.